# Issue with VBA in excel for enabling/disabling of Cells

Tags: vba

Requirement Explanation :-
Whenever specific input given in some field/column of excel then the user should be restricted to input for specific range of fields/columns in the same row and same sheet of excel.
Input is selected from dropdown values in each cell of fields/columns.
Other than those specific input, those specific range can be allowed for user input.
This applies for all the rows of the input column until the last cell.

Example Scenario :-
If user selects "AWB" from dropdown in the cell C6, then user should not able to provide input from DP6 to ED6 (DP6 - ED6 should be read only/not editable).
Else DP6 - ED6 cell should be enabled. (Here, we have enabling and disabling in the same row) .
Note : And no other sheet should be impacted because of this.

My code :-

```
WorkBook.Sheets("SheetName").Unprotect

WorkBook.Sheets("SheetName ").Range("A15:A20").Locked = False

mainworkBook.Sheets("SheetName ").Protect
```

Comment: Where is this code located? What is the rest of if? Are you using the `Worksheet_Change` event?

Comment: Hi,    That's the only syntax I am using. There is nothing else I am using for that. Actually I am new to VBA. I want to disable a range of cells which are in the same row like if I give some input in A3 then D3 to K3 cells should be disabled. This shouldn't effect any others cells. That to without protecting entire sheet. Please help me in this.

Comment: Hi Bigaben,  Can you please help on this. I am not able to proceed with this code....

Comment: The posted answer should be helpful for you. You'll need to make a few modifications but I think it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example taken from the [PCreview](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/how-do-i-disable-cell-editing-in-vba.3475819/) website that makes column F read-only. This can be adapted to make any cells read-only.

```
Dim OldValue As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 6 Then
        On Error GoTo Whoops
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        MsgBox "Values in this column cannot be changed!"
        Target.Value = OldValue
    End If

Whoops:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 6 Then OldValue = Target.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: @chinni power - Did this answer your question?